# HackerRank - Bear and Steady Gene

Tags: c#, algorithm, strings, programming-challenge

[Problem statement](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/hourrank-6/challenges/bear-and-steady-gene)

First version:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BearAndSteadyGene2
{
class BearAndSteadyGene2
{               
    /*
     * Nov. 28, 2016
     * 
     */
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int number = practice(8, "GAAATAAA"); 
    }

    /*
     * Nov. 28, 2016
     * 
     */
    private static int practice(int n, string input)
    {                      
        int[] a = new int[1007];             

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[input[i]]++; 
        }

        int ans = Int32.MaxValue;
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[input[i]]--;
            while (valid(n, a) && index <= i)
            {
                ans = Math.Min(ans, i - index + 1);
                a[input[index]]++;
                index++; 
            }
        }

        return ans; 
    }

    private static bool valid(int n, int[] a)
    {
        int A, G, T, C;
        A = a['A'];
        G = a['G'];
        T = a['T'];
        C = a['C'];
        if (A <= n / 4 && G <= n / 4 && T <= n / 4 && C <= n / 4) return true;
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Based on the code review on [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142808/quick-sort-algorithm/142853#142853), I wrote a new version:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BearAndSteadyGene2
{
  class BearAndSteadyGene2
  {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int testCase1 = minChange(8, "GTAAAAAA");
        Debug.Assert(testCase1 == 4);

        int testCase2 = minChange(8, "GATAAAAA");
        Debug.Assert(testCase2 == 4);

        int testCase3 = minChange(8, "GAAATAAA");
        Debug.Assert(testCase3 == 5);             

        int testCase4 = minChange(8, "AAAGTAAA");
        Debug.Assert(testCase4 == 6);
    }



    /*
     * Nov. 28, 2016
     * code review based on the blog:
     * https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142808/quick-sort-algorithm/142853#142853
     * 
     * 1. change the variable name from i -> right, index -> right, 
     * therefore, 2 pointers are very clear: left and right, both pointers moves forward only
     * 2. First, get the count for each char; 
     *    and then, use two pointers, first right point moves forward, the substring 
     *    from left to right position will be replaced, stop when the rest of string fits 
     *    the requirement: <=n/4.
     *    Record the length; and then, move left pointer until it breaks the requirement. 
     *    Continue the iteration on the right pointer again. 
     * 3. Add 4 test cases
     * 4. error handling - ? 
     * 5. Consider adding postcondition assertions: 
     *    Debug.Assert
     */
    private static int minChange(int n, string input)
    {           
        int[] a = new int[4];             

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            char c = input[i];
            a[indexOf(c)]++;
            Debug.Assert(indexOf(c) != -1);  // add postcondition assertions
        }

        int ans = Int32.MaxValue;

        // two pointers: left and right, both go through O(n) time
        int left = 0;
        for (int right = 0; right < n; right++)
        {
            char c1 = input[right]; 
            a[indexOf(c1)]--;

            while (valid(n, a) && 
                   left <= right)
            {
                ans = Math.Min(ans, right - left + 1);
                char c2 = input[left]; 
                a[indexOf(c2)]++;
                left++; 
            }
        }

        return ans; 
    }

    private static int indexOf(char c)
    {
        string code = "ACGT";            
        return code.IndexOf(c);
    }
    /*
     * Nov. 28, 2016
     */
    private static bool valid(int n, int[] a)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] > n / 4)
                return false; 
        }

        return true;                
    }
   }
 }
```

[Source code link](https://gist.github.com/jianminchen/124b33e3d7aa0276e7b6ea4542c8ad5b)

1. Line 26 - 36, add 4 test cases, with 4 postcondition assertions
2. Function name is changed to `minChange`
3. Line 61, array of size 4 is declared instead of 1007
4. Function `indexOf()` is added
5. Variable names are changed, left, right, two pointers, move forward only
6. Added two explanations for variables `c1` and `c2` to avoid a complicated expression
7. Valid function is declared using a `for` loop

Please provide  your code review advice. I tring to get C# advice, coding style, and algorithm design advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few comments:

- In C#, method names should be PascalCased, not camelCased.
- In `minChange`, you should use meaningful variable names for `a`, `c`, `c2`
- In `minChange`, you can set `var ans = int.MaxValue`, unless there is a compelling reason avoid using `Int32` when you can use `int`, same with `Int16` vs `short` or `Int64` vs `long`.
- In `indexOf`, you can use a `const string code = "ACGT";` instead. This gives some compiler optimizations.
- In `valid`, (and `minChange`) you should use meaningful parameter names, `n` and `a` don't have any contextual meaning.

Comment: I also try to figure out how to help user understand left pointer needs to move forward, highlight the sliding left pointer one step forward in the function minChange: after the line: ans = Math.Min(ans, right - left + 1);  Because I did not get the idea of moving left pointer as well until I debug the code with those 4 test cases. Any advice related to marketing the idea, those 3 lines of code:  char c2 = input[left]; 
                a[indexOf(c2)]++;
                left++;

Comment: It would be a lot more apparent if you used meaningful variable names for `a` and `c2`.

Comment: Great advice, "int[] a " is better to name "int[] geneChars" (gene chars's count), "char c2" is better to name "char moveOut" (move out from replaced substring).

Answer (score 2):

A few more comments:

- `int number = practice(8, "GAAATAAA")` - this tells me absolutely nothing about what the called method is about. Give the method a better name.
- Why `8` in `Main`, why `1007` in `practice`, why `4` in `valid`? Don't use magic numbers.
- I think it would be more intuitive to write `if (A <= n / 4 && G <= n / 4 && T <= n / 4 && C <= n / 4) return true; return false;` as `return (A <= n / 4 && G <= n / 4 && T <= n / 4 && C <= n / 4);`
- It seems quite awkward to have a class with the same name as the namespace.

Comment: I did a research on hackerRank Bear and steady gene algorithm submission, I did study over 100 submissions. One of C++ solution is here:https://gist.github.com/jianminchen/c6b51207f9cc9b083573, the code works perfectly, so I wrote a C# version. Your review is helpful, but I did work on a new version to overcome those pitfalls.